# Ошибка: [Error] Objects.pas(97): Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found

Tags: ооп, типы-данных, delphi, delphi-7, классы

Построил систему классов

```
unit Objects;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
type
  TDataTypeID = (DataTypeId_String, DataTypeId_SmallInt, DataTypeId_Integer,
  DataTypeId_Word, DataTypeId_Boolean, DataTypeId_Float, DataTypeId_Currency,
  DataTypeId_BCD, DataTypeId_FMTBCD, DataTypeId_Date, DataTypeId_Time,
  DataTypeId_DateTime, DataTypeId_Timestamp, DataTypeId_Bytes, DataTypeId_Varbytes,
  DataTypeId_Blob, DataTypeId_Memo, DataTypeId_Graphic, DataTypeId_FMTMemo,
  DataTypeId_FixedChar, DataTypeId_WideString, DataTypeId_LargeInt, DataTypeId_Array,
  DataTypeId_FixedWideChar, DataTypeId_WideMemo);
type
  TAlignSpec=(AlignSpec_Left, AlignSpec_Right, AlignSpec_Center);
  TDomainSpec = class(Tobject)
  private
    FName : String;
    FDescription : String;
    FDataTypeId : TDataTypeId;
    FLength : Cardinal;
    FCharLength : Cardinal;
    FPrecision : Cardinal;
    FScale : Cardinal;
    FWidth : Word;
    FAlignSpec : TAlignSpec;
    FShowNull : Boolean;
    FShowLeadNulls : Boolean;
    FThousandsSeparator : Boolean;
  public
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property DataTypeId: TDataTypeId read FDataTypeId;
    property Length: Cardinal read FLength;
    property CharLength: Cardinal read FCharLength;
    property Precision: Cardinal read FPrecision;
    property Scale: Cardinal read FScale;
    property Width: Word read FWidth;
    property Align: TAlignSpec read FAlignSpec;
    property ShowNull: Boolean read FShowNull;
    property ShowLeadNulls: Boolean read FShowLeadNulls;
    property ThousandsSeparator: Boolean read FThousandsSeparator;
  end;
      TTableSpec=class;
      TFieldSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FPosition : integer;
    FName : string;
    FDescription : string;
    FCan_input : Boolean;
    FCan_edit : Boolean;
    FShow_in_grid : Boolean;
    FShow_in_details : Boolean;
    FIs_mean : Boolean;
    FAutocalculated : Boolean;
    FRequired : Boolean;
    FTableSpec : TTableSpec;
    FDomainSpec : TDomainSpec;
  public
    property Position : integer read FPosition;
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property Can_input : Boolean read FCan_input;
    property Can_edit : Boolean read FCan_edit;
    property Show_in_grid : Boolean read FShow_in_grid;
    property Show_in_details : Boolean read FShow_in_details;
    property Is_mean : Boolean read FIs_mean;
    property Autocalculated : Boolean read FAutocalculated;
    property Required : Boolean read FRequired;
    property TableSpec : TTableSpec read FTableSpec;
    property DomainSpec : TDomainSpec read FDomainSpec;
  end;
  TTableSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FName : string;
    FDescription : string;
    FCan_add : Boolean;
    FCan_edit : Boolean;
    FCan_delete : Boolean;
    FFields : array[1..100] of TFieldSpec;
  public
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property Can_add : Boolean read FCan_add;
    property Can_edit : Boolean read FCan_edit;
    property Can_delete : Boolean read FCan_delete;
    property Fields : array read FFields;
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

При этом в TTableSpec свойство Fields должен быть списком полей (я использовал массив TFieldSpec). Каким образом организовать список полей (используя или не используя массив), т. к. в результате компиляции получаю ошибку

```
[Error] Objects.pas(97): Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found
[Error] Objects.pas(97): READ or WRITE clause expected, but identifier 'FFields' found
[Error] Objects.pas(98): Type expected but 'END' found
[Hint] Objects.pas(90): Private symbol 'FFields' declared but never used
[Fatal Error] FirstTask.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Objects.pas'
```

Comment: Такая иерархия строится на основании TCollection и TCollectionItem. При этом нет необходимости заботиться о создании элементов, удалении, доступе по индексу и т.д. Посмотрите в vcl реальзацию TFields, TFieldDefs.  
Ваш массив режет глаз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо было использовать следующий синтаксис

```
property Field[Index : Integer] : TFieldSpec read GetField;
```

И разумеется реализовать функцию в разделе implementation

```
function TTableSpec.GetField(Index : Integer) : TFieldSpec;
begin
   Result:=FFields[Index];
end;
```

Comment: Весьма интересный вариант, в нем есть огромный плюс - соблюдение инкапсуляции.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
type
    TFieldSpecArray = array[1..100] of TFieldSpec;

TTableSpec=class(Tobject)
    private
        //...
        FFields : TFieldSpecArray;
    public
        //...
        property Fields : TFieldSpecArray read FFields;
```

Ибо массивы в качестве типов некоторых параметров недопустимы.